# Admob integration errors

Tags: iphone, admob

I have integrated AdMob into my application, but when I try to display any ads, it gives me the following errors:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONDeserializer", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-CJSONDeserializer in libAdMob.a(AdMobAd.o)
objc-class-ref-to-CJSONDeserializer in libAdMob.a(AdMobSearchViewController.o)
objc-class-ref-to-CJSONDeserializer in libAdMob.a(AdMobOpener.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONSerializer", referenced from:
objc-class-ref-to-CJSONSerializer in libAdMob.a(AdMobAd.o)
objc-class-ref-to-CJSONSerializer in libAdMob.a(AdMobWebView.o)
objc-class-ref-to-CJSONSerializer in libAdMob.a(AdMobFlexWebView.o)
```

Does anyone have any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i got solution for this, This just happen because of admoblib.a file and i clear cache and reinsert it into my project and now it works fine..